# Glance index error Openstack

Tags: linux, openstack

When i config Openstack using Souce Code, there is a question about "Glance Index", get the error as Blow

```
    Failed to show index. Got error:
    Response from Keystone does not contain a Glance endpoint.
```

but when execute keystone endpoint-list there has result,

is there some has the same problem?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of threads on this in the OpenStack dev mailing list archives:

1. [Glance is not able to find an endpoint in response from keystone](http://openstack.markmail.org/thread/nhlnxjj7zmsumgms)
2. [Essex keystone with remote glance endpoint](http://openstack.markmail.org/thread/duunpxq235xgfaoz)

From the first thread, have you tried double checking that the Glance endpoint is registered under the "image" service in Keystone?

You'll probably have to go into the database to confirm this. You might have to use "keystone endpoint-create" to put a valid endpoint in there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks your Answer, on my configure, when i execute keystone endpoint-list the result as below:`[root@nova tools]# 
keystone service-list

+----------------------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------+
|                id                |     name    |     type     |        description        |
+----------------------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------------+
| 0820c98b9e424b15a271598b98d235dc |    glance   |    image     |    Glance Image Service   |`   

you can see that glance image service has already existed.

Comment: Ah, I see. You might want to edit your question and include that information right in the question (it kind of looks like you thought about including it after "result,"). You might also want to include exactly what version of OpenStack you're using and which packages.